# recorrer 12 archivos csv con UTL_FILE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, plsql

Amigos, este es el código que estoy haciendo para recorrer 12 archivos CSV, sin embargo solo esta leyendo el ultimo archivo, pueden ayudarme

```
PROCEDURE SP_CARGA_POLY_EXTERNA (V_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2, V_MENSAJE_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2)  
     IS
     V_SECUENCIA NUMBER :=1;
     F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
     LFILE VARCHAR2(100); --:= 'FILES_IN-'||V_SECUENCIA||'.csv';
     V_ROW VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_T_CARGA_POLY SDBX_GDOC.DE_CARGA_POLY%ROWTYPE;
     I     NUMBER := 0;     
     V_NO_EXISTE_ARCHIVO EXCEPTION;
     BEGIN
       V_ERROR := 1;      
       WHILE V_SECUENCIA<=11
       LOOP                 
       --FOR I IN 1..12 LOOP       
       --UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F,V_SECUENCIA);           
       LFILE:='FILES_IN-'||V_SECUENCIA||'.csv';
       V_SECUENCIA := V_SECUENCIA + 1;
       END LOOP;        
       F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(V_NOM_DIR,LFILE,'R');                
       IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SDBX_GDOC.DE_CARGA_POLY';        
         LOOP           
           BEGIN
             UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F,V_ROW);
             IF I > 0 and LENGTH(V_ROW)>20 THEN
               V_T_CARGA_POLY.NO_ARCH_GDOC     := LFILE;
               IF SUBSTR(LFILE,INSTR(LFILE,'IN',1,1),2)='IN' THEN
               V_T_CARGA_POLY.TI_OPER          := 'CUSTODIA';
               ELSE
               V_T_CARGA_POLY.TI_OPER          := 'PRESTADO';
               END IF;                  
               V_T_CARGA_POLY.CA_POLY          := FN_OBTENER_VALOR_COLUMNA(V_ROW,1);
               V_T_CARGA_POLY.DE_OPER          := FN_OBTENER_VALOR_COLUMNA(V_ROW,2);                              
               INSERT INTO SDBX_GDOC.DE_CARGA_POLY VALUES V_T_CARGA_POLY;               
             END IF;
             I := I + 1;                          
             EXCEPTION
               WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
               EXIT;               
           END;           
         END LOOP;
         COMMIT;         
       END IF;                           
       IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
       --UTL_FILE.FREMOVE(V_NOM_DIR,LFILE);
       END IF;       
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN V_NO_EXISTE_ARCHIVO THEN
         V_ERROR := '-5000';
         V_MENSAJE_ERROR := 'NO EXISTE ARCHIVO POLY EN LA RUTA';
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         V_ERROR := SQLCODE;
         V_MENSAJE_ERROR := 'SP_CARGA_POLY_EXTERNA, '||SQLERRM;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que tienes un ciclo que *construye* los nombres de los archivos (solamente 11, no 12), pero no realizas nada con el nombre de archivo dentro de ese ciclo. Hasta que has salido de él (y solamente el nombre del último está en la variable `LFILE` abres el archivo que tenga ese nombre y lo procesas.

Quizás lo veas más claro si mejoras la indentación de tu código y eliminas código viejo que no utilizas (en comentarios), por ejemplo:

```
PROCEDURE SP_CARGA_POLY_EXTERNA (V_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2, V_MENSAJE_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2) IS
   V_SECUENCIA NUMBER :=1;
   F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   LFILE VARCHAR2(100); --:= 'FILES_IN-'||V_SECUENCIA||'.csv';
   V_ROW VARCHAR2(2000);
   V_T_CARGA_POLY SDBX_GDOC.DE_CARGA_POLY%ROWTYPE;
   I     NUMBER := 0;     
   V_NO_EXISTE_ARCHIVO EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   V_ERROR := 1;
   /* acá inicia el ciclo que construye 10 nombres de archivo */
   WHILE V_SECUENCIA<=11
   LOOP                 
      LFILE:='FILES_IN-'||V_SECUENCIA||'.csv';
      V_SECUENCIA := V_SECUENCIA + 1;
      /* acá tenemos el nombre del archivo en la variable, pero no hacemos nada con él ya que */
   END LOOP; /* aquí termina el ciclo */
   /* a partir de acá tenemos el nombre del último archivo en la variable, que debiera ser 'FILES_IN-11.csv' */
   /* no he cambiado nada abajo, creo que acá queda claro tu error. */
   F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(V_NOM_DIR,LFILE,'R');                
   IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SDBX_GDOC.DE_CARGA_POLY';        
     LOOP           
       BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F,V_ROW);
         IF I > 0 and LENGTH(V_ROW)>20 THEN
           V_T_CARGA_POLY.NO_ARCH_GDOC     := LFILE;
           IF SUBSTR(LFILE,INSTR(LFILE,'IN',1,1),2)='IN' THEN
           V_T_CARGA_POLY.TI_OPER          := 'CUSTODIA';
           ELSE
           V_T_CARGA_POLY.TI_OPER          := 'PRESTADO';
           END IF;                  
           V_T_CARGA_POLY.CA_POLY          := FN_OBTENER_VALOR_COLUMNA(V_ROW,1);
           V_T_CARGA_POLY.DE_OPER          := FN_OBTENER_VALOR_COLUMNA(V_ROW,2);                              
           INSERT INTO SDBX_GDOC.DE_CARGA_POLY VALUES V_T_CARGA_POLY;               
         END IF;
         I := I + 1;                          
         EXCEPTION
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           EXIT;               
       END;           
     END LOOP;
     COMMIT;         
   END IF;                           
   IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
   --UTL_FILE.FREMOVE(V_NOM_DIR,LFILE);
   END IF;       
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN V_NO_EXISTE_ARCHIVO THEN
     V_ERROR := '-5000';
     V_MENSAJE_ERROR := 'NO EXISTE ARCHIVO POLY EN LA RUTA';
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     V_ERROR := SQLCODE;
     V_MENSAJE_ERROR := 'SP_CARGA_POLY_EXTERNA, '||SQLERRM;
END;
```

La indentación, a menos que uses python, es completamente ignorada por las computadoras. La idea de indentar el código es ayudar a los humanos (a ti mismo para empezar) a hacer más fácil de entender el código que lees (a veces a medida que lo escribes).